# Load all third party scripts using requests or mechanize in Python

Tags: python, django, screen-scraping

I am loading web pages into an iframe and I want to make sure I make all the associated media available. I am currently using requests to download the page and then doing some find/replace, but that doesnt have full coverage. Is there a way with python to get a list of all scripts, css and image requests the page makes when its loaded into a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## BeautifulSoup

Use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get all the `<img>`, `<link>`, and `<script>` tags then pull the corresponding attributes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get("http://www.yahoo.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

# Pull the linked images (note: will grab base64 encoded images) 
images = [img['src'] for img in soup.findAll('img') if img.has_key('src')]

# Checking for src ensures that we don't grab the embedded scripts
scripts = [script['src'] for script in soup.findAll('script') if script.has_key('src')]

# favicon.ico and css
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll('link') if link.has_key('href')]
```

Example output:

```
In [30]: images = [img['src'] for img in soup.findAll('img') if img.has_key('src')]

In [31]: images[:5]
Out[31]:
['http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130925/My_Yahoo_Defatul_HP_ad_300x250.jpeg',
 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png',
 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png',
 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png',
 'http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-95031.png']
```